# My code run very slow, how can I make it faster

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code to see which numbers have the condition `a**4 + b**4 + c**4 = d**4`

But the code I typed is very slow. Do you have any suggestions to make it faster?

(I know this code is not suitable for Python language but asking me to optimize this code in the language I know.)

```
import math
import datetime


def main():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()

    for a in range(1, 100000):
        a = pow(a, 4)
        for b in range(1, 300000):
            b = pow(b, 4)
            for c in range(1, 500000):
                c = pow(c, 4)
                d = (a + b + c) ** 0.25
                separated_num = math.modf(d)
                if separated_num[0] == 0:
                    if a + b + c == d:
                        print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}, d = {d}, time = {datetime.datetime.now() - t}, ", end='')
```

Comment: You're trying to do 54 bits of work (`log2(100000 * 300000 * 500000) == 53.735...`). This wouldn't go fast even in a low-level compiled language (it's within rounding error of cracking DES, which is doable with dedicated hardware and well-optimized code in hours or days IIRC, but not doable in Python in a few minutes). You need a better algorithm, not merely tweaks to improve performance.

Comment: You are using a brute-force approach which requires 15,000,000,000,000,000 iterations (that's 15 quintillion). Even if each iteration took a nanosecond (not happening even in low-level languages) then this would take [173.6 days](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=15000000000000000+nanoseconds) to compute. You need a better algorithm

Comment: The answer should be that there are none - this is the extended form of the Fermat Last Theorem, and iirc it was only disproved for powers higher than 5

Comment: What do you need this for? The ranges look odd.

Comment: First, your code is not running very slow.  It is running very fast, but you are attempting too many loops.  It will not finish in your lifetime.  Second, using `(a+b+c)**0.25` is never going to work.  Fractional exponents have to use logarithms, which are always going to be approximations.  That means you will never get an exact answer.  Third, there are no solutions to this.  Even if you ran it until it ended 3 years from now, you would get no answers.  Please go after REAL problems.

Comment: Fourth, your equations are wrong.  You set `d = (a+b+c)**0.25` then check `if a+b+c == d:`.  That will never be true.

Comment: @EricJin I don't see it on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem). Can you link to it?

Comment: @KellyBundy I finally found it again, it's [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf), a counterexample to the Euler conjecture. (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_sum_of_powers_conjecture)). Well, I was wrong, but you already have the solutions there, and finding anymore will take you way too long.

Comment: @TimRoberts `**0.25` [can succeed](https://tio.run/##LYo9DoAgFMZ2TvGNisSA8hQGDoM/URclhMXTI0anJm3Dnfbr7E2IOXuBSWCGgyUjpUCnRlJWQCtNg2TJx21NJXvONRpMH@YCthR9nKn6H84h245qFuJrl/d0Dl@tc34A).

Comment: Okay, you have no idea what algorithm I can use
I know that using these nested loos is not a good solution at all
But no other thought came to my mind
Has there really been no solution to this problem that can be answered quickly?

Comment: @KellyBundy  -- I stand corrected.  However, the `(a+b+c)**0.25 == a+b+c` thing is still going to doom this.

Comment: No.  This is one of those class of problems which can only be solved through brute force searching of every possible combination.  There are no shortcuts.  As the Wikipedia page shows, there are multiple solutions, but only one with values below a million.  This is a solved problem.  What's the point?

Comment: Okay, thank you
They gave me this code in c language and asked me to optimize it in a language I know
But I did everything I could and asked anyone I could
I'd better let go of this

Comment: @TimRoberts Where can I find the proof that there are no shortcuts?

Comment: Who are "they" who gave you this, and why did they give it to you? If it's not just some guys fooling around but this is a school or interview problem or so and you are *expected* to be able to find something faster, then presumably there is.

Comment: You could somewhat speed it up using modulo. For example modulo 10. Fourth powers modulo 10 always end with digit 0, 1, 5 or 6. So for example if `a` and `b` both have last digit 1, then their sum ends with digit 2. And adding any `c` would lead to last digit 2, 3,  7 or 8. So there can't be any fitting `d` and thus you don't even need to try any `c` if `a` and `b` both end in 1.

Comment: Or put differently, if `a` ends with 1, you don't need to check any `b` ending with 1. And maybe you don't even need to try every `a`, at least for some moduli.

Comment: Looks like for modulus 195, only about 1 in 62 combinations of a, b and c would need to be tried.

Comment: pow(a, 4) can be optimized as ((aa:= a*a) * aa)

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics and feasibility aside, here's an O(n^2) approach to optimize your O(n^3) solution.

```
MAX_VAL = 660000
dp = []
two_sums = []
two_diffs = {}

for i in range(MAX_VAL):
    dp.append(i**4)

for i in range(2,MAX_VAL):
    for j in range(1,i):
        two_sums.append((dp[i]+dp[j], j, i))
        two_diffs[dp[i]-dp[j]] = (j,i)

for val in two_sums:
    if val[0] in two_diffs:
        a,b = val[1], val[2]
        c,d = two_diffs[val[0]]
        if a+b+c == d:
            print(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: Doesn't work right. Which I suspect you already know, because why else would you write `if a+b+c == d`?

Comment: If you use cubes, you can test it with much smaller MAX_VAL.